# Qt how to decode string in Qt 4.7 (old method are gone)

Tags: qt, decode, qurl

Im using Qt 4.7.1 and im trying to find way to decode url 
from :
 https://xxx.com&since=2011-01-27T10%3A33%3A50%2B0000
to vaild date , but i can find any way to do it now .. it used to be QUrl::decode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [`QString QUrl::fromPercentEncoding ( const QByteArray & input ) [static]`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qurl.html#fromPercentEncoding)